# Time out event occurred while executing GnuPG using C#

Tags: c#, encryption, gnupg, openpgp

I am running a decryption process on millions of files and I am using GnuPG for this.

After the job running for couple of minutes it is closing abruptly with the following error:

```
ERROR: Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.GpgException: Error.  Action: Decrypt.  Command args: --passphrase-fd 0 --no-verbose --batch --trust-model always --decrypt  ---> Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.GpgException: A time out event occurred while executing the GPG program.
   at Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.Gpg.ExecuteGpg(ActionTypes action, Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.Gpg.ExecuteGpg(ActionTypes action, Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
   at Starksoft.Aspen.GnuPG.Gpg.Decrypt(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream)
```

I have written a batch job and tried to schedule it, that fails as well after couple of minutes. I don't see a configuration file either in the GnuPG folder if I need to change any timeout settings.

Answer (score 0):

GnuPG does not timeout. The timeout is triggered by the `Starksoft.Aspen` GnuPG C# interface you're using. Looking at the code, it seems that the [default timeout is 10 seconds](https://github.com/bentonstark/starksoft-aspen/blob/master/Starksoft.Aspen/GnuPG/Gpg.cs#L135) and the timeout can be [configured through setting the `TimeOut` property](https://github.com/bentonstark/starksoft-aspen/blob/master/Starksoft.Aspen/GnuPG/Gpg.cs#L220). I'm not used to C# and that framework, but it seems to boil down to something like

```
gpg.TimeOut = 120000; // Set timeout to 120 seconds
```

Reading through the MSDN documentation on [`Process.WaitForExit(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it seems that a timeout value of `Int32.MaxValue` will disable the timeout entirely:

```
gpg.TimeOut = Int32.MaxValue; // Disable timeout
```